# Is void a type?

Tags: java, void

I can't answer completely "why should we call "**void**" is '**return type**'?"

*How do I prove that "**void**" is a type?*

Answer (score 12):

`void` is not a type, it is not also a return type:

in [JLS 14.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8) you can find a note about this type:

> Note that
>   the Java programming language does not allow a "cast to void"-**void is
>   not a type**

Comment: That proves it's a type. Doesn't prove it's a return type.

Comment: @EJP, void is a type, but not a return type. I've changed my post a bit.

Comment: the JLS states it the other way (JLS 8.4, 18.1) and a counter proof: a local variable declaration is defined as "[final] Type VariableDeclarators ;" in the JLS. Then `void someName;` would be a valid variable declaration if `void` was a Type.

Comment: @Carlos, I was wrong - I've found official note that void is not a type, thanks for pointed this.

Answer (score 10):

The [Java Language Specification](https://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html) [says that](https://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#24888):

> [...] every variable and every expression has a type that can be determined at compile time. The type may be a primitive type or a reference type.

`void` is not a [valid type](https://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.1). However, `void` is a valid [keyword](https://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.9) used to indicate that a [method does not return a value](https://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#37508).

The [Void JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) also says that `void` is a keyword:

> The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void

Contrast that to the [Integer JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html):

> The Integer class wraps a value of the primitive type int in an object. An object of type Integer contains a single field whose type is int.

The `Void` class represents the `void` **keyword**; while the `Integer` class represents an `int` **type**.

Answer (score 2):

Quote:

> TYPE
>
> public static final Class TYPE
> The Class object representing the primitive Java type void.

Taken from :  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html

Or have I misunderstood the question?

Answer (score 2):

Hope 
[class void](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) explains why void is a type.

> The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a
>   reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.

```
public final class Void extends Object
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, void is definitely type, meaning 'nothing'.
By the way, do you mean C (C++, Objective-C, ...).
Couldn't say for any language, but in C (C++, Objective-C, ...) void is a type.
But it is special data type. You couldn't declare variable of type void. That's differ void from any other types.
But you could declare pointer to void. Function which return value is void means function has no return value, or returns nothing. That's afraid all cases where void type could be used.
void * v; /** declares variable v as pointer to void */
*v used as left value in expression could be assigned value of any type without type cast. That's why void type was introduced into language.

You updated your question, underlining you were asking about Java. Java has no pointers and no functions. void type is used in declarations of methods returning nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Any class method must specify a return type. The 'void' keyword can be specified, specifying that it has no return type, for example:

```
public void SetPantsSize(int width);
```

There is also a void class: 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html

Answer (score 0):

Void is a type in most languages, and given the typical type system, it makes the most sense to think about it as a type that specifies "nothing". You didn't state your language, but for example, in C#, the `void` keyword corresponds to the [.NET framework void type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.void.aspx).

Comment: Or in Java? Or any other language the defines a `void` keyword?

Comment: @Femaref: Still a type, an incomplete one to be precise.

Comment: I jumped the gun, I thought I saw C# in the tags. I updated the answer to say "in most languages", which is true in my experience.

Answer (score -1):

`void` is a type in the Java language (you can read that directly in the Java Language Specification).
However the type `void` has no member values, that is no concrete value will ever have the type void. `void` is therefore used to indicate that a method cannot return a value when called (that is `void` is the type of "no value").

Comment: please at least point where I can read it in the JLS! I only found that `void` is a ResultType, which is a Type or a `void` (JLS 8.4)

Comment: The JLS uses uses `void` as a type in the setting of method return types: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.5

Comment: "The return type ... declares the type ..., or states that the method is void." - it's a type **OR** a void. "... with return type R1 ... If R1 is void" - a return type, not a type.